# Update data after desired time

Tags: php

I want to update record in database after click submit and wait 30 seconds for example.
I was trying to use sleep() but it doesn't look fine (page is refreshing 30seconds).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){ 
    echo "Start!";
    $sql = 'UPDATE players SET money = money + 1 WHERE nick = "player" ';
    mysql_query($sql, $connection);
}
?>


<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Start"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Use google to search for "Ajax"...

Comment: PHP is only on the server. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: http://devzone.co.in/automatically-save-data-after-specific-time-interval-using-jquery-php/